# How to pass a parameter along

Tags: prolog, parameter-passing

I am new to Prolog. I want to implement a function that calculates the size of a list of lists. For example I have `[[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[12,ab]]` and the value returned should be `8`. So I have this code:

```
  size([], _).
  size([_|T], X):- X1 is X + 1, size(T, X1).

  total_size([], X):- write('size = '), write(X).
  total_size([H|T], X):- size(H, X), total_size(T, X).
```

But my function returns `0` all the time. My plan is to pass `X` to the `size` function and increment the value of `X` every time I call `size`. The query is:

`?- total_size([[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[12,ab]], 0).`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,

Corneliu

PS: I know I am not supposed to use the word "function" anywhere near "prolog".

Comment: Yep. They're "predicates" that express logical "relations". They aren't "functions" that "return" values. It's not just a nomenclature thing. :)

Comment: You could also do: `total_size(L, X) :- flatten(L, LF), length(LF, X).`

Comment: @mbratch: Thank you very much. Your solution works well. Would you like to write an answer and get the rewards? If you do, I will mark it as solution. If not, then I'll answer my own question. PS: I don't care about legalities (predicates, relations, functions). Those who invented prolog are obviously a bunch of masochistic sadists or sadistic masochists, whichever you prefer.

Comment: @mbratch: Sorry, I didn't realize that CapelliC has fixed his solution and it works now. Since he already posted the answer, I will mark his answer as solution.

Comment: No worries at all. I really just offered it as an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about size/2 could 'return' a value. A value can only be 'returned' binding a parameter (we call them an argument). Then the first step should be to correct the first clause (as we call the 'code').

```
size([], 0).
```

This is a relation, saying that an empty list has size 0.

Now the recursive step can be corrected also: it will *use* the value of the recursive call, then

*edit* correcting my bug

```
size([_|T], X):- size(T, X1), X is X1 + 1.
```

You can see, values 'flow back' from the computed steps.

total_size/2 it's different, since the computed value must be displayed at the end of the recursion (well, these are loops, really). Computed values 'flow down' the calls. Just, you forgot to add the values returned by size/2.

```
total_size([], X):- write('size = '), write(X).
total_size([H|T], SoFar):- size(H, X), Sum is SoFar + X, total_size(T, Sum).
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I think there are errors in your code. If I try to run it, swipl throws an error: `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` I guess because X1 is not instantiated in line 2 and X is not instantiated in line 4. I don't know which compiler you use. I must use swipl.